# Failling to start the local development server with Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I run the dev_appserver in the google CLI I get the following response:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
[main 2022-10-07T09:05:01.667Z] update#setState idle
[main 2022-10-07T09:05:02.651Z] Starting extension host with pid 9172 (fork() took 14 ms).
[main 2022-10-07T09:05:31.674Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2022-10-07T09:05:31.739Z] update#setState idle
[17620:1007/120702.026:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(481)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

I checked for answers for the "GL is disabled" problem and I found the webGL extensions from "chrome://flags/" and enabled them, but it still gets stuck like this (waited for as long as 20 min, nothing else returned) Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What Platform/OS is this - Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: Windows and Python 2.7

Comment: Maybe it's from your application. Are you doing anything with Selenium or Electron? Can you try a basic 'hello world' app and see if it runs?

Comment: Thanks, solved it! I uninstalled VS code and it worked (I think the google sdk was using VS code as an interpreter instead of python)